# Is there a benefit to turning off dynamo-powered lights?

Tags: lighting, dynamo

I have a bicycle with lights and a hub Dynamo. I am looking for generic answers that apply to more setups but if that's not possible, the bicycle I have is a [Stevens Randonneur 2021](https://www.stevensbikes.de/2021/index.php?bik_id=126).

My bicycle lights can be turned off using a switch on the back of the front light. I was wondering if there is any benefit to turning them off during daytime. Two possible ones that I could think of (but don't know if are actually true):

1. More efficient riding, as no power is redirected to keep the lights on. Probably tiny, even if true.
2. Less 'wear' on components. The light and other components maybe last longer if not turned on unnecessarily.

Are the above true? Are there any other benefits?

Comment: Loss of some visibility to others is almost always a negative when not running at least some lighting. So if you are riding on a controlled path with little traffic and no motor vehicle traffic, it may be warranted to run without lights. However if you are in the proximity of motor vehicles, a few watts is a small price to pay for what may be your life if hit by a driver who does not notice you.

Comment: @TedHohl in sunlight typical dynamo lights offer almost nothing in the way of visibility - far less than a jersey that contrasts with the expected background.  But if you pass into deep tree shade the rear light (and the front on a narrow road) suddenly become very helpful indeed. That's a common occurrence where I ride, and partly why I leave mine on.

Comment: @ChrisH - I wasn’t aware of the poor performance of a dynamo-powered light (I remember having one on my bike as a kid, but that was half a century ago).  Today’s LED light options are vastly superior that what was available even 10-15 years ago.  I run a front light on my bikes that is the size of a one-inch cube, and it lasts many hours on a charge. It is not as much a headlight as it is for visibility. It also takes up very little space on the bar so the cockpit stays lean. Similar (red) setup on the rear. Total weight is maybe 3 oz/80 g for both.

Comment: @TedHohl I've never used anything but modern LEDs with my dynamo, but they're all built to illuminate the road efficiently, which isn't the same thing as being seen in high light levels. The rear is more useful, but still, if I want to be noticed from a long way off in daylight, I'll turn on a flashing backup that would be dangerously bright at night in that mode.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Yes, there is an efficiency gain by turning the lights off.

[Cyclingabout](https://www.cyclingabout.com/dynamo-hub-power-drag-testing-schmidt-son-shutter-precision-shimano/) made a hub dynamo comparison based on an experiment by [skjegg](https://skjegg.blogspot.com/2020/02/dynamo-hubs-for-your-pleasure.html), where power consumption was measured for different dynamos attached to different lights.

To give you ballpark figures, let's use the example of the Busch & Muller IQ-X light. The first graphic shows pedaling drag (dashed line) and output electrical power (solid line) for when the light is on.

[image: Pedalling drag and output power for different hub dynamos with B&M IQ-X connected]

The second graphic shows pedaling drag with lights disconnected, which is similar to turning the light off.

[image: Pedalling drag with light off]

By having an hub dynamo installed, you constantly loose around 1.5 - 5 W (at speeds above 15 km/h - lights off scenario). However, depending on light and dynamo, **by keeping the lights off you can save around 8 - 11 watts**.

An important follow-up question would be: **does it matter in practice?**

According to [bikecalculator](http://bikecalculator.com/), for a 100 kg rider + bike system, flat, no wind, one needs about 115 W to cruise at 25 km/h and 39 W to ride at 15 km/h. Let's see how faster one could ride if this extra drag were to be converted into forward movement. I will use data from the Shimano 3D32 (the one I see most often) and assume that the calculator does not take into account hub dynamos.

So:

- 15 km/h (39 W):

  - +2.5 W (41.5 W total effort - hub dynamo & lights off) would equal 15.5 km/h, i.e. approx. 0.5 km/h faster;
  - +13.0 W (52 W total effort - hub dynamo & lights on) would equal 17.42 km/h, i.e. approx. 2.4 km/h faster.
- 25 km/h (115 W):

  - +3.5 W (118.5 W total effort - hub dynamo & lights off) would equal 25.24 km/h, i.e. approx. 0.2 km/h faster;
  - +10.5 W (125.5 W total effort - hub dynamo & lights on) would equal 25.85 km/h, i.e. approx. 0.8 km/h faster.

Note that these values are for instant speed. The average speed difference would be smaller.

EDIT: I originally made a mistake on interpreting the graphic that skewed the results significantly to the draggier side, thanks @jpa.

Comment: Wow, those internal dynamo losses are much larger than I expected. Thanks for providing experimental measurements. You have my upvote :-))

Comment: +1 but note that the IQ-X is one of the most powerful dynamo lights around, so results for more common lights will be a bit less

Comment: The IQ-X is unusually powerful but it still draws only 2 watts more than the halogen lights dynamos were originally designed for. It would be interesting to compare these results with losses when the dynamo runs at 3 watts.

Comment: The above graph would be summarized more fairly by saying that the power "losses" due to the light on are between 5W and 10W. Rounding up to 10W is on the generous side...

Comment: Also note, that those drag numbers for "lights off" mode seem to be too large. Other tests seem to come in much lower, e.g., 0.25 W to 1.25 W for the SON dynamos tested at 10km/h-30km/h as referenced here https://www.cyclingabout.com/dynamo-hub-drag-lab-testing/     (I wanted to mention it for completeness so that people can check out the other studies and don't get a wrong impression about how bad a dynamo hub is compared to a regular hub!)

Comment: Thank you for the edit — +1. So the interpretation: SON28 at 20 km/h, switched on, takes about 10 W, of which 4.5 W is lost to drag and 5.5 W is available to lights/chargers; SON at 20 km/h, switched off, takes about 1.3 W. Is this the correct interpretation?

Comment: @gerrit No, at 20 km/h 5.5W is lost to drag and 4.5W is available to the light. Otherwise your interpretation is correct.

Comment: @ojs while I do have a halogen dynamo light in my possession (it's handy for testing if nothing else) but an extra 2W on a 3W nominal output is quite a high percentage difference.  The regulators needed to stop halogen lamps blowing when going fast weren't great either, wasting power, but then going fast with those lights would have been quite scary

Comment: @ChrisH it was already debated to death under other answer, but I'll recap it here: For loads that are roughly like incandescent bulbs (resistive load under maybe 5 ohms) dynamos behave like current sources that are limited to 0.5 A. For the 3W bulb it would mean that the dynamo would not output much more than 6V no matter how fast you ride.

Comment: @ojs that's an approximation that I'm familiar with, and it holds quite nicely up to a point, partly because the bulb is also self-regulating to some extent. But push it hard enough and the approximation fails, followed shortly by the bulb. I have a 2.4W shimano hub that makes a point of its regulator engraved on the outside

Answer (score 11):

In general I leave mine on all day (SP-PD8 and Axa luxx 70) but it does take a little extra pedalling effort. A few Watts is likely to be a couple of percent of your effort, but if you were into marginal gains you probably wouldn't be riding with a dynamo in the first place. I do save the effort in bright conditions when the lights are of very little help, if I remember, and especially uphill.

The main reason to turn the lights off in my case is that then I can charge my phone from the dynamo as my light has a 5V USB socket.

Inside the dynamo, nothing will wear faster for drawing a current and the electrical parts don't move against parts they touch. LED lifetimes are at least tens of thousands of hours. Judging by mine the plastic lens will degrade before then, from little scratches.

Answer (score 3):

Many answers already state that there can be efficiency gains, but:
There can as well be efficiency *loss* from turning off the light.
This depends on the circuitry involved.

For example, if you turn off only the front light (many rear lights can not be turned off individually), the voltage generated by the dynamo will be higher.
Instead of the typical 6V (RMS), it may produce 15V.
The rear light may have a protection device (TVS diodes), which clamps the voltage at 12V.
Now, as soon as the voltage would exceed 12V, much current will flow through the TVS diodes.
This is probably less power than what the front light would consume, but it may be more power.

There are also dynamos with integrated TVS diodes.
These are known to make more drag when not connected than when shorted.

---

Years ago I have made experiments with a Shimano 3D32.
Of couse I can not link references for these experiments.

This model generates a kind of sine wave when under normal load and speed.
In an open circuit it adds a sharp spike in the middle of each half wave.
It generates an RMS voltage of about 1V per km/h, so at a typical speed of 20km/h it generates 20V RMS, which is much more than the rated 6V.
The peak voltage is about 4V per km/h, so 80V at 20km/h.
If you touch the wires of the unloaded dynamo at this speed, it actually hurts a lot!

The Shimano 3D32 is able to deliver much current if it is allowed to reach this peak voltage.
I connected a 24V TVS diode, and at 20 km/h it burned about 15W.
Therefore: If you have this dynamo, a rear light with 24V TVS diodes, and turn off your front light, you should actually notice the efficiency loss.

Comment: I have managed to burn the protection diodes in a halogen headlight when the bulb was broken and I did not notice it right away. It was a bit unexpected.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the electronic design of your light and dynamo but as of the time of writing it is rather inefficient and the drag is not non-existent.

A bicycle dynamo historically produced [between 1.2 and 2.4 W](https://www.sheldonbrown.com/marty_light_hist.html) so the lamp could not be more powerful. LEDs are typically at least ten times more efficient (6 W LED shines like [60 W incandescent](https://www.beleuchtungdirekt.ch/de/osram-vintage-1906-led-e27-birne-fadenlampe-gold-6-5w-725lm-824-extra-warmweiss-ersatz-fur-60w-4058075293298?channable=404790736b75003430353830373532393332393872&qcd=1&utm_gst=b618babc39ec7b2706000e392a95bc799c79806b&productid=4058075293298&gclid=Cj0KCQjwteOaBhDuARIsADBqReiafgEy3LqupqbRvURFSkwqHIRK0QQg8cTK4USituxCT8nBA7i5PsYaAqQSEALw_wcB) bulb, bright enough as a primary beam of a car). It would kind of be logical to expect the modern dynamo LED light to draw 0.1 W at moderate brightness but nope, looks like the majority of the recent dynamo lights still draw up to 10 W of power instead. They should shine like 100 W light often seen as too bright for a living room, what are they doing with this power?

This is likely tied to dumb/naive solutions that are used to convert the varying voltage of dynamo into fixed voltage required for the LED. While the efficient converter can be easily built, a [simplest naive stabilizer](https://www.petervis.com/electronics%20guides/voltage-regulator-using-transistor/voltage-regulator-using-transistor.html) is highly inefficient and looks like exactly these are still mostly used.

Hence your dynamo light may be creating up to 10 W of drag resistance that depending on your fitness and overall situation may make it unreasonable to keep it always on.

Comment: Those 4.5 volt torches were also incredibly dim compared to even non-halogen dynamo lights. 1.125W LED would be unnoticeable during day, and maybe just barely enough for riding if there aren't other light sources around and you have enough time to adapt to dark.

Comment: Added the source that specifically references bicycle lights. 1.2 to 2.4 W so mostly that I said.

Comment: You conveniently ignored the part that says 1.2W is tolerable "for riding at a moderate pace once the eyes were dark-adapted". If you got the 6W from where I think, you should probably be aware that the light is unusually powerful and the standard is 2.4 or 3 W.

Comment: Please take a look at calofr's answer: https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/86359/36555

Comment: Also, even if an LED light only needs 0.2W of power, the light would still need to draw at least 3W from the dynamo. This is necessary to avoid the voltage skyrocketing and frying the LED: The dynamo is designed to deliver the correct voltage across a large range of bicycle speeds *under the assumption that it can feed 0.5A into the system*. Take away the current drain, and you get voltages that hurt.

Comment: @cmaster-reinstatemonica no, the light would need to be designed to be capable of operating with variable voltage, which it _should_ be. (Yes, many aren't, but that's just bad design.)

Comment: @leftaroundabout You are forgetting that there may also be a rear light connected to the same dynamo. The rear light never drew as much power as the front light, and simply relies on the presence of a front light in order to not get toasted. I have some first hand experience with that where a failed front light caused the rear light to get toasted.

Comment: @cmaster-reinstatemonica yeah, but again – there's no good reason nowadays to have lights, whether front or rear, incapable of surviving much higher voltage than the rated one. Of course the manufacturer can save a couple of cents by omitting this circuitry, and many will do it (perhaps reasoning that if one light goes then the users may anyways just replace both), but that doesn't change the fact that it's wrong.

Comment: This seems to be an answer based on what could be achieved in theory, rather than what is achieved in practice.

Comment: "Reality is wrong, my opinion is how things should be" is an easy but not very productive way to approach problems.

Comment: Looks like even high end dynamo lights are not using the modern power converters and draw about the same power as the older halogen lights, relying on the stabilizers of 1970s design for mitigating the wide voltage range of dynamo. Shame, they probably do not see 10 W as worth considering. I have adjusted the answer. May be a good idea for a startup.

Comment: Do you know anything about electronics, really?

Comment: Yes. I was designing and building my own electronic device that required the power converter, and since then I know that such converters exist, what they can do and how much do they cost. I am surprised that this technology is not used with these lights.

Comment: Can you link to this power converter, and maybe explain how it works with bike dynamos? Dynamos are weird.

Comment: The converter like https://www.distrelec.ch/en/dc-dc-converter-72v-5v-fixed-recom-78he5/p/30165009 can take from 6.5 till 72 V and output 5 V, up to 1.5W. Its efficiency is 83 %. Larger voltages are getting dangerous already.

Comment: I have measured 50V from just spinning an hub by hand, so I wouldn't be surprised if fast riding would go over 72V. The other question is, what are you going to do with the extra current that the dynamo is pushing when the converter takes 0.2A or less.

Comment: @ojs the dynamo is _not_ “pushing extra current”. In the efficient operation domain, it acts as a constant-voltage source; it's not a problem at all if the currents are arbitrarily small. On the contrary, what's a problem is when the current is too big such that the voltage drops and you get the constant-current behaviour you describe. Nightrider is exactly right that these lights are just braindead designs; I too am surprised that they seem to be still common. (Moreso since the last dynamo light I had, about 10 years ago, did have proper regulating circuitry.)

Comment: @leftaroundabout please come back when you understand that bike dynamos are not constant-voltage sources even though they look like that when connected to 2 ohm resistive load.

Comment: @ojs they're certainly _not_ constant-voltage with a load as low as 2 Ω, but that's irrelevant. They are constant-voltage _when the current is kept low enough_, that's what matters. A reasonable equivalent resistance for a dynamo light is something like 200 Ω (but of course the regulating circuit will mean this constantly varies).

Comment: @leftaroundabout I'm sorry that I have to ask about this, but are you writing about how you think dynamos should work without any connection to reality, or how they actually work? And just for reality check, what is this constant voltage that you keep mentioning in volts?

Comment: @ojs how they actually work. The source I used: http://pilom.com/BicycleElectronics/HubDynamo.htm, admittedly rather amateurish but don't see a reason to doubt the correctness. The constant-voltage region is the linearly rising part on the left of the  vs  diagram, i.e. up to 150 mA for the Shimano DH; the voltage looks like 25 V at 15 km/h, or 60 V at 40 km/h. The constant-current region is the dropping part on the right of the diagram, starting at about 220 mA.

Comment: @leftaroundabout interesting, but to me it looks like they measured one hub dynamo that has produces voltage that is roughly linear to speed when connected to current sink that is set up to take a specific current that is less than half of the specified. I agree that it is not constant-current with load that is that far out of spec, but I wouldn't call it exactly constant voltage. I also don't see why the results are generalisable, when the bottle dynamo they measured is clearly different, or why the generator would be efficient when it's run far outside spec.

Comment: @ojs the “specified current” really just tells what current the dynamo can reliably provide without risk of overheating. It's not the current that the dynamo is _supposed to be operated at_, nor the current at which it provides the most power (that happens in the middle at the transition between constant-voltage and constant-current domains), and definitely not the current where it's most efficient (on the contrary, the constant-current domain is when most of the energy is wasted to internal resistance).

Comment: @leftaroundabout do you have any sources for the "supposed to be operated at"? To me the whole thing still looks like it's a designed around the now obsolete idea that the dynamo should be able to power a 3 watt bulb without voltage regulation and it can do anything when the load is radically different.

Comment: @ojs The design goal of bike dynamos was to power a 3W light bulb without voltage regulation *across a large range of bike speeds*. You didn't want your bulb to blow out just because you were descending at 50km/h+, but you also wanted full "brightness" from 20km/h+. This lead to the current design of dynamos, where you have a rather complex anchor that alternates the magnetic flow through a fixed coil. A design that is specifically *not* designed to guarantee that the magnetic field lines actually cross through the copper windings, producing power. This design persists even in hub dynamos.

Comment: @cmaster-reinstatemonica I know that. I'm looking for a source for the idea that dynamos are supposed to operated or most efficient at 190 mA.

Comment: @ojs I'm not saying they're supposed to be operated at specifically 190 mA either. You're both way overinterpreting what a dynamo does. It's just a magnet and a coil with multiple poles. It behaves, in essence, no different from any other generator/brushless-motor: voltage is proportional to ∂/∂ of the magnetic flux minus · losses through wire resistance . At sufficiently low current, the magnetic field of the wire is negligible so all the ∂/∂ comes from movement of the magnet, and the · is also negligble. So that's a const-voltage source, and thus can be...

Comment: ...used this way like any other generator/motor, which is what's done in most applications because this is the most efficient working domain. What @cmaster-reinstatemonica is referring to is that the single-coil design of the dynamo has a higher self-inductance than multi-coil ones, i.e. at high speed & high current the wire's own field counteracts the ∂/∂ from the magnet-rotation. For most motors/generators this is a negative effect; for the old light bulb use it happened to be useful to prevent overvoltage, but that doesn't mean a dynamo must or should always be operated in that domain.

Comment: @leftaroundabout thanks for the explanation

Comment: @leftaroundabout Couldn't have said it better :-)